# Password Resetting Error In Python  Flask Framework

Tags: python, flask, jwt, change-password

I was watching the Flask Miguel Tutorial [Flask Miguel Tutorial - Email Support](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support) and was developing a blogging web application.

But I am facing errors in resetting the password. When an email come to my mail inbox, I click the link as per taught by Miguel and the following errors appear:

```
Exception on /reset_password/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZXNldF9wYXNzd29yZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg4OTg4NDYyLjgzMzI3Mn0.6TDngRn3uQ1bAc4JniTY8kOWROwsqJcxZRB3MA6dKQQ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeetkhondker/Projects/memoryblog/blog_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/jeetkhondker/Projects/memoryblog/blog_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/Users/jeetkhondker/Projects/memoryblog/blog_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/jeetkhondker/Projects/memoryblog/blog_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I have copied the code as same as it is in the Flask Miguel Tutorial. But I cannot reset my password.

Code for Reset Password:

```
@app.route('/reset_password_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = ResetPasswordRequestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            send_password_reset_email(user)
        flash('Check your email for the instructions to reset your password')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('reset_password_request.html',
                           title='Reset Password', form=form)


@app.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password(token):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.verify_reset_password_token(token)
    if not user:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your password has been reset.')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('reset_password.html', form=form)
```

Is there any expert who have gone through this issue can help me to solve my problem?

Thanking you for your support as always.

Comment: Show us the code of the method for reset password handling

Comment: @CodeYard: 

The post has been edited including the reset password handling code.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace

Comment: I dont understand "Full Stack Trace"

Comment: I mean the full error message. Can you see which line is causing the error

Comment: @CodeYard:
That is the full error message. 

Error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` According to the Flask Miguel Tutorial, I have done same to same, but it is showing that error. If you have gone through this before, can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: I have used that code before

Comment: I have added the error as well.

Comment: Can you specify which line is the error

Comment: I could not find it, so I need your help. The code is all same to same as the tutorial of Miguelberg.

Comment: Ok let me see. Are you sure that all the templates exist

Comment: Yes all templates exists.

Comment: I got the solution. I have misspelled form attribute name "password" in html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a misspell of the word "password". That is the reason of the problem.